# Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server error "unable to access user principal information from the system"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, kerberos, ssrs

When I launch the Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server and try to connect to the local machine it's on, I am getting the error "Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server error "unable to access user principal information from the system"

Google searches return minimal results.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/717d6821-f3f4-43a6-8bba-5eb4804df499/unable-to-access-user-principal-information-from-the-system-error-when-trying-to-launch-kerberos?forum=sqltools

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/717d6821-f3f4-43a6-8bba-5eb4804df499/unable-to-access-user-principal-information-from-the-system-error-when-trying-to-launch-kerberos?forum=sqltools

I am working in a single domain with a single account.  None of the users on this system are orphaned or displaying a GUID instead of their ID.

I really want to use this tool to help troubleshoot my Reporting Services kerberos issues.

The log generated by the tool is displaying the following errors:

```
9/16/2014 11:43:05 AM Info: Connect to WMI, \root\cimv2
9/16/2014 11:43:37 AM Error: Access of system information failed System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070035): The network path was not found.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.ResolveCrossStoreRefToPrincipal(Object o)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMMembersSet.MoveNextForeign()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMMembersSet.MoveNext()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, TSource value, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at KerberosCM.WMIHelper.TryIsUserLocalAdmin(SystemInfo si, UserPrincipal user, Boolean& isLocalAdmin)
9/17/2014 8:36:08 AM Info: Connect to WMI, \root\cimv2
9/17/2014 8:36:10 AM Error: Access of system information failed System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070035): The network path was not found.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.ResolveCrossStoreRefToPrincipal(Object o)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMMembersSet.MoveNextForeign()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMMembersSet.MoveNext()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, TSource value, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at KerberosCM.WMIHelper.TryIsUserLocalAdmin(SystemInfo si, UserPrincipal user, Boolean& isLocalAdmin)
```

Comment: I suppose your permissions are sufficient, right?

Comment: What permissions do I need?  I'm in the administrators group on the server.  I've installed it on the server and I'm connecting locally.  I can perform setspn -l commands so I should have sufficient permissions.

Comment: Are you running it as a local user or domain user? Are you giving it the local or domain user credentials (when it asks)?

Comment: I am running it as the account which I'm logged into the server as, which is a domain user.  I'm not giving it any credentials since I am connecting to the local machine.  I have tried providing the domain user credentials as well and that didn't work either.

Comment: When you "point it" to the local machine, are you using the FQDN, short name, or something else? Try using the FQDN and supplying the domain credentials.

Comment: Is there anything in the Kerberos Configuration Manager Log file that provides more details on what is happening? Files are located in the following path: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\KerberosConfigMgr

Comment: Adam, thank you so much for responding to my tweet.  I've updated the question to include the errors showing up in the log.

Comment: The instructions for the tool state no server name needs to be entered.  However, I've tried it both ways and they still fail.

Comment: When you run it, try either setting it to run as an administrator or right-clicking and choosing run as admin when launching.

Comment: I tried that as well.  Still not working.

Comment: have you managed to resoble this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this is a really old post, but for anyone that is still having this issue... I managed to work around it by going into my local administrators group on the server and clearing out any accounts showing up as a GUID.

Once I did that, I was able to launch the tool, fill in no server/user info and just hit connect.  It logged right in after that.

(I know the original poster said he already checked for that, but this is what resolved this issue for me).

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but I was having the same issue.  In my case the Remote Registry service was not running.  I have found that on some servers it is just running, and on others it shows Automatic (trigger start), and in both of those cases I can use the tool successfully.  If the service is manual/disabled, etc... and not running, this error occurred.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was similar to the other answers but slightly different.  I had an account from another domain in the Local Administrators group.  I'm not sure the exact type of trust that was present.  After removing that account the tool was able to run.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on SQL 2016 hosted on a Windows Server 2016.

Running as admin didnt resolve my problem. I had to '**Run as a different user**', then I logged in as my **Active Directory domain admin**. Then I was able to connect to the hosted SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Got exactly the same problem, How I fixed it?

> I went to local users and groups on the server with SPN issues
>   Groups>Administrators> and removed any account that is not part of the same domain as the server.

I had a user account from another domain, after removing it and trying the App again it worked.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing the GUID entry from the local Administrator group, I had to run the tool remotely from another machine on the domain in order to avoid the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting an error when connecting to the SQL server with **Kerberos Configuration Manager**. My local admin group was clean, but I was also getting a WMI error when launching **Sql server Configuration Manager**. "Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable, Note that you can only manage SQL Server 2005 and later servers with SQL Server Configuration Manager.
Invalid class [0x80041010]"  I followed this article to Recompile SQL WMI provider using mofcomp "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/tools/error-message-when-you-open-configuration-manager" and that worked for both **Sql server Configuration Manager** and **Kerberos Configuration Manager**.